# Remove all but specific highways in osmosis

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis

I want to display entire country OSM data in my application.
The problem my application don't know how to deal large maps.
Instead of chunking the map into 5-10 small chunks, I wish to display only the following items:

```
highway=trunk, highway=trunk_link, highway=primary,highway=primary_link, highway=secondary, highway=secondary_link,highway=tertiary,highway=tertiary_link ,highway=motorway, highway=motorway_link
```

All roads but residentials. I don't want to show rails, polygon shapes (area, landuse, parks.. etc..) Only roads!

But after running this command:

```
osmosis.bat --read-xml "C:\belgium-latest.osm" --tag-filter accept-nodes highway=trunk, highway=trunk_link, highway=primary,highway=primary_link, highway=secondary, highway=secondary_link,highway=tertiary,highway=tertiary_link ,highway=motorway, highway=motorway_link --write-xml "C:\belgium-latest-highwayOnly.osm"
```

I still have the other shapes (not only highways) and the osm file is too big.. it shrunk only 25%~.. i hoped it to be smaller.

I am doing something wrong ? should i add objects to **reject-nodes** attribute ?

Comment: the tool i started using instead osmosis is osmfilter with the following: osmfilter.exe belgium-latest.osm --keep="highway=primary =primary_link =trunk =trunk_link  =secondary =secondary_link =tertiary =tertiary_link =motorway =motorway_link, =residential =residential_link " >bel_highway_all.osm

Comment: I also recommend to try http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter as an alternative to osmosis ... try to read all ist documentation in the OSM wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax looks odd, please try the original code snippets and alter them step by step till you get the desired results:
https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis#Example_usage
It's also wise to start with an pretty small area, so your processing is fast and doesn't prevent you from testing :)